Wordpress redirect infinite loop
I have a domain and hosting at http://eventusleuven.be.
I have an Elementor page on a subdomain, http://foodbase.eventusleuven.be.
I now bought a new domain, and I want to link this domain to Elementor page on the other site. By using a CNAME or an A record: https://thefoodbase.be
define('WP_HOME', 'https://thefoodbase.be/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://thefoodbase.be/');

# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]       # Block access to files in wp-admin/includes directory
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]            # Skip the next three rules if the request is not for a file in wp-includes directory

    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]  # Block direct access to PHP files in wp-includes directory
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]  # Block direct access to PHP files in tinymce/langs directory
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]              # Block access to files in wp-includes/theme-compat directory
</IfModule>

<Files wp-config.php>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        require all denied
    </IfModule>
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

I would expect that it stays on the "thefoodbase.be" instead of being redirected someway to "foodbase.eventusleuven.be".
I tried changing the APP_URL etc in Elementor, but I don't feel like I could solve it that way. I rather feel like I'm forgetting something.

None of the code you've posted so far seems to handle redirects from http://foodbase.eventusleuven.be to https://thefoodbase.be though.

Hi @cabrerahector, thanks for your response! Is it required to have such additional redirecting in the code? As far as I understood, the URL would never change to "http://foodbase.eventusleuven.be" as the WP_URL's and CNAME are set to "https://thefoodbase.be".
